# Refit saying it cant find the authentication method yet it works in swagger

Tags: c#, refit

I am trying to use  [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit)  but am having an issue it says its cant find my authenticate method when trying to login a user form the client side. Refit is a strongly typed httpclient replacement. Im wondering is it cause I'm using the FromBody attribute in the swagger side?

Base url is stored in a var

```
public const string APIUrl = "https://localhost:44315/api";
public interface ILoginAPI
{
    [Post("/Users/")]
    Task<Token> Authenticate(User user);
}
```

My user Controller has the function defined as

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("Authenticate")]
public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody] AuthenticateRequest model) {
        var response = _userService.Authenticate(model, ipAddress());
        if (response == null)
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect" });
        setTokenCookie(response.JwtToken);

        return Ok(response);
}
```

My Token is here as a class

```
public class Token
{
    public bool Authenticated { get; set; }
    public string Created { get; set; }
    public string Expiration { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And here is me trying to consume it its a web api project that has jwt berrer token and that functionality works as it stands.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     var loginAPI = RestService.For<ILoginAPI>(Constants.APIUrl);
        Token token = loginAPI.Authenticate(
            new User()
            {
                Username = "David",
                Password = "Test12345",
            }).Result;
     
        var mytokenHere = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(token);
        var test = token.Authenticated;
        
        return View();
}
```

Cause when I look at swagger ui all it shows me is username and passsword here which works.

[image]

Results

[image]

But why when I am attempting to do it thru refit is it not finding the api call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decorate the parameter you want to use as the body of your request with [Body] attribute

```
public const string APIUrl = "https://localhost:44315/api";
public interface ILoginAPI
{
    [Post("Authenticate")]
    Task<Token> Authenticate([Body]User user); // => parameter decorated with [Body]
}
```

you can look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#body-content) for more info

Comment: Still getting this thanks but its not helped
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).)'

Comment: @csharpdude77 wondering if its because the path is set as `/Users/` instead of `Authenticate`